# How do I mitigate exceptions from constructors of aggregated objects if my own constructor must not throw without resorting to "new"?

Tags: c++, exception

My C++ class aggregates a helper object which may throw an exception in the constructor, but my own class must not throw (my own class is used by a framework which is not prepared for exceptions being thrown by a constructor). Right now I mitigate this risk by delaying the construction of the helper object by creating the object using `new` so that I'm able to catch any exceptions:

```
struct HelperObject {
  HelperObject() {
    throw 0;
  }
}

struct MyObject {
  HelperObject *o;
  MyObject() : o( 0 ) {
    try {
      o = new HelperObject;
    } catch ( ... ) {
      // ...
    }
  }
};
```

However it's a bit annoying to abuse `new` for this; I suddenly have to deal with a pointer for the entire code for no good reason except that it allows me to get more control over the time at which the object is constructed.

Is it possible to achieve something to this effect without usign `new`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could use smart pointer and an extra MakeHelperObject function so that exceptions are done inside HelperObject domain. This only makes MyObject code clean but exception still need to be processed during HelperObject construction:

```
struct HelperObject {
  HelperObject() {
    throw 0;
  }

   static HelperObject* MakeHelperObject()
   {
     try
     {
       HelperObject* p = new HelperObject();
       return p; 
     }
     catch(const SomeException& e)
     {
      // deal with e
    }
    return NULL;
  }
};


struct MyObject {
  std::unique_ptr<HelperObject> o;
  MyObject() : o(HelperObject::MakeHelperObject())
  {
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, no, as you need to suppress the exception and you can only do that with a try block, and function try blocks won't allow you to suppress the exception. It sort of begs the question of how the framework is going to behave if it thinks it successfully constructed the object which now has a big hole in it.

You should consider using an scoped pointer to automatically deallocate the `HelperObject`. It makes for more resilient code.

Comment: The framework calls an `isValid` function right after constructing my object to see whether the object is valid or not (don't blame me!).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe As someone who has also had to use external libraries with dubious architectures, I cannot but sympathise with you in this case.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe My sympathies too.